# How to find the rotation, which minimizes the volume of the bounding box

Tags: geometry

Given a point cloud sampled evenly from a surface, how do I find the rotation, which minimizes the bounding box of it?

The first idea was to do a PCA to align the principal directions with the cartesian coordinates. But for example a cube has the diagonals as principal coordinates, which rotates him in the worst position for the axis aligned bounding box.

Is there an (computational) easy way to find the axes, which minimize the bounding box of the shape?

Comment: Step 1: find the convex hull and throw away the points. Why? Because it's possible for almost all the points to be near one corner of the chull, but the best bbox won't change. But anything based on moments of the point set *will* change. (Also: the chull is likely to be a far smaller structure on average).

Comment: Actually a cube is entirely degenerate because its inertia matrix is a multiple of the identity: any orthogonal basis is equally good according to PCA. (And the diagonals are not an orthogonal set anyway.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms

Comment: Let me add, that the points are sampled from a surface of a (possibly not convex) object. The goal is to find some offset surface. The idea here is to find a minimum bounding ellipsoid, where an ellipsoid of the bounding box is sufficient. This should possibly extended to a surface sampled using the mahalanobis distance as metric, when it's computationally feasible and then be triangulated. All parts should work best, if the points are rotated into a position, which minimizes the axis aligned bounding box.